# Python ignore element in list/tuple if appears once over a certain time range

Tags: python, list, filter

So I'm new to python and am having some problems with a list (might even be a tuple), nevertheless I have one rogue point I want to remove in the list below i.e. 64. It is not as simple as removing / ignoring the point as the value will appear in later in the data multiple times.

I've tried several things including filtering, new list and having a time check i.e if less than 25 seconds then ignore, but nothing is quite getting it.

```
2018-05-09T01:21:15.424999  33 
2018-05-09T01:51:15.680999  33
2018-05-09T02:21:15.94  33
2018-05-09T02:51:16.211 33
2018-05-09T03:21:16.468 33
2018-05-09T03:51:16.74  33
2018-05-09T04:21:17.011 33
2018-05-09T04:51:17.262 33
2018-05-09T05:21:17.532999  33
2018-05-09T05:51:17.82  33
2018-05-09T06:21:18.092 33
2018-05-09T06:51:18.377999  33
2018-05-09T07:21:19.208999  33
2018-05-09T07:51:19.528999  33
2018-05-09T08:21:19.831 33
2018-05-09T08:28:11.1   64
2018-05-09T08:28:35.561112  33
2018-05-09T08:58:36.043 33
2018-05-09T09:28:36.255 33
2018-05-09T09:58:36.632 33
2018-05-09T10:28:36.995 33
2018-05-09T10:58:37.283 33
```

Comment: Please create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What is the criterion for removing? The specific number 64? What do you mean with the 25s test?

Comment: Hi criterion for removing is if it occurs only once. I've tried a count function but it doesn't work as expected. I tried a time range so if '64' appears for less then 25 seconds using a time difference i.e. between 33 then it ignores it , but failed to work.

Comment: I've tried too much code to really post it.

Comment: Any suggestions on this one ? I have now attempted to look for a pattern i..e where the list is a. last_a = a , print last_a , a but how do I look at the next value i.e. last_a = 33 , a = 64 and next a = 33 then I can do a continue and ignore the 64 . Any one ?

Comment: If it's not too much data, read in the whole thing in a list first. Otherwise, keep the information you need while reading more lines, such as the time and value of the last line.